# Сборка проекта mvn

Tags: maven, npm, project

не пойму с чем связана ошибка при сборке проекта и как её решить.

```html
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (build) @ summercamp ---

> test-project@1.0.0 build /home/aldnoah/summercamp
> webpack

sh: 1: webpack: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! test-project@1.0.0 build: `webpack`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the test-project@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/aldnoah/.npm/_logs/2018-04-30T21_48_13_185Z-debug.log
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:764)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:711)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.797 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-05-01T00:48:13+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (build) on project summercamp: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Версии:

java/javac 1.8.0_171
 mvn 3.5.3
 npm 5.6.0
 ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Искал в интернете, ничего годно не нашел.

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

UPDATE: файл зависимостей

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <groupId>summercamp</groupId>
    <artifactId>summercamp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.threewks.thundr</groupId>
        <artifactId>thundr-gae-app</artifactId>
        <version>5</version>
    </parent>

    <scm>
        <connection>${scm.url}</connection>
        <url>${scm.url}</url>
        <developerConnection>${scm.url}</developerConnection>
    </scm>

    <properties>
        <scm.url>scm:git:git@gitlab.com:stav-community/summercamp.git</scm.url>
        <appId>${project.artifactId}-${project.activeProfiles[0].id}</appId>
        <appVersion>1</appVersion>
        <gae.version>1.9.54</gae.version>

        <!-- Usd by parent for thundr-gae -->
        <thundr.version>3.0.0</thundr.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- Profiles define the environments available. The active profile determines what environment you're deploying to when running appengine:update or similar -->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>uat</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>tag-deployment</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>tag</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>tag-deployment</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>tag</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>3wks-maven-repo</id>
            <url>s3://3wks-maven-repo/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.threewks.thundr</groupId>
            <artifactId>thundr-gae-user</artifactId>
            <version>${thundr.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.threewks.thundr</groupId>
            <artifactId>thundr-contrib-gmail</artifactId>
            <version>${thundr.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.threewks.thundr</groupId>
            <artifactId>thundr-handlebars</artifactId>
            <version>${thundr.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Additional or overridden dependencies go here -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-appengine</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-gson</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.openpojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>openpojo</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hashids</groupId>
            <artifactId>hashids</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <tag>${appId}-v-${appVersion}-${build.time}</tag>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Maven's build timezone is always in UTC so that's why we use this. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/35578881/945789 -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.12</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>timestamp-property</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>timestamp-property</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <name>build.time</name>
                            <pattern>yyyyMMdd-HHmmss</pattern>
                            <locale>en_AU</locale>
                            <timeZone>AET</timeZone>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- This plugin runs the static asset build at the appropriate lifecycle points of the maven build -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution> <!-- Clean static resources during mvn clean -->
                        <id>clean</id>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>npm</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>run</argument>
                                <argument>clean</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution> <!-- Install JS dependencies during mvn initialize -->
                        <id>install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>npm</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>install</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution> <!-- Build static resources during mvn generate-sources -->
                        <id>build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <environmentVariables>
                                <NODE_ENV>production</NODE_ENV>
                            </environmentVariables>
                            <executable>npm</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>run</argument>
                                <argument>build</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution> <!-- Run static resource tests during mvn test -->
                        <id>test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>npm</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>run</argument>
                                <argument>test</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gae.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <address>0.0.0.0</address>
                    <port>8081</port>
                    <disableUpdateCheck>true</disableUpdateCheck>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.kuali.maven.wagons</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-s3-wagon</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
    </build>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
</project>
```

Comment: судя по всему, webpack не установлен глобально

Comment: @etki установил webpack глобально. Не помогло. 
Почему вы выдвинули такое предположение? Хочу узнать нюансы, чтобы можно было определить в будущем проблемы. )

Comment: `sh: 1: webpack: not found` говорит о том, что процесс пытается запустить бинарник webpack, но он отстуствует в текущем окружении

Comment: А если в `package.json` добавить `"scripts": { "build": "webpack" }`, и запускать его `npm run build`. И сейчас cli от него вынесен в отдельный пакет, попробуйте еще `npm i -g webpack-cli`